# How to make from json to text in node js

Tags: node.js

I got this code and I get `{ prize: 'Run' }`, but I want to get "`Run`"

```
const inquirer = require("inquirer");

inquirer
  .prompt([
    {
      type: "list",
      name: "prize",
      message: "What do you want to do",
      choices: ["Run", "Settings",]
    }
  ])
  .then((answers) => { 
    console.log(answers);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const inquirer = require("inquirer");

inquirer
  .prompt([
    {
      type: "list",
      name: "prize",
      message: "What do you want to do",
      choices: ["Run", "Settings",]
    }
  ])
  .then(({ prize }) => { 
    console.log(prize);
  });
```

You can destructure the object if you need. Prompt takes a list of questions so it cannot just resolve just a single for multiple questions.